# What to use instead of strlen() for a device driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux-device-driver

Ubuntu 20.04
output of `uname -a`

```
Linux station 5.4.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 23 19:20:19 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am trying to write a simulated device driver. My understanding is that I have to use kernel headers, and that the c standard library is unavailable to me.
I wrote a program that simulates read/write, etc, to disk, in user space, using standard library functions. Now I am refactoring, converting malloc to kmalloc, etc. I use strlen() from string, and was trying to find a kernel space equivalent.
This led me to kernel api doc
https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/ch02s02.html
This is where I am confused. In this section titled basic c library functions it lists, among others, strlen().
Is this the standard c strlen from string.h, or from some other header? If it is the standard string.h , then I need to read more because my understanding of what may be included in linux device drivers is incorrect.

Comment: Some of c apis have kernel version. Eg: `printf` to `printk`. And some are supported in kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
String functions for kernel space can be used with

```
#include <linux/string.h>
```

I just had to keep looking.

Comment: It's annoying that the kernel documentation doesn't tell you which functions are declared in which headers.

Comment: @NateEldredge I was expecting more from the documentation.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I suggest you to learn the tools and this won’t be a problem. I have no issues with finding declarations (macros are beasts, but it is a different story).

Comment: To OP: using `strlen()` in ~80% of cases means either you are doing something wrong or you don’t know the proper in-kernel API. I suggest to show the code excerpt for better suggestions.

Comment: @0andriy I am trying to. Im trying to go the extra mile with a school project. This is my first time with the kernel API.